# Simple edit dialog box

Tags: c++, dialog

I am modifying a program that runs in Windows that I would like to input a couple of values into as it starts.

At the beginning of AppMain, the following pre-existing code allows the user to enter a filename:

```
char our_file_name[260] = "TEST";

#ifdef WIN32
edit_dialog(NULL,"Create File", "Enter file name:", our_file_name,260);
#endif
```

This all seemed rather straightforward so I thought I'd just recreate this for my (signed) integer values, with the following code, inserted immediately following the above code:

```
#ifdef WIN32
edit_dialog(NULL,"Custom tolerance", "Enter tolerance:", tolerance,260);
#endif

#ifdef WIN32
edit_dialog(NULL,"Custom position", "Enter intended position:", position,260);
#endif
```

... And the following placed with the other variable declarations:

```
int tolerance = 400;
int position = 0;
```

The code compiles just fine, but when I run the program, the filename section works just as it should but the program crashes as soon as this new bit starts to run.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better method of inputting a couple of values?

Comment: Would be useful if we could see the `edit_dialog` function.

Comment: Is there an overload for `edit_dialog` that expects an `int` rather than a `char*`? Can you post the signature of the applicable versions of `edit_dialog`? You need to provide a bit more information..

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought edit_dialog would have been a Windows standard function. Is there an more standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature for the `edit_dialog` function probably takes a char* as it's 4th parameter.  You are passing an int there when you call it with `tolerance`, so your code is treating the value of the int (in this case 400) as a pointer value (0x400) and going to look at the string located at the address 0x400... Boom. Crash.

You need to write the integer value to a character buffer before you pass it in to the `edit_dialog` function.

```
char buf[256];
sprintf( buf, "%d", tolerance);
#ifdef WIN32
edit_dialog(NULL,"Custom tolerance", "Enter tolerance:", buf, 260);
#endif
```

(I bet edit_dialog is a macro, because I'm pretty sure most compilers would catch this error at compile time and warn you).

Then when your edit dialog comes back, it will store the characters the user typed back into buf which you'll probably want to convert to an int.

```
tolerance = atoi(buf);
```

Comment: Thank you very much - does the line "sprintf( buf, "%d", tolerance);" transfer the value in buf to the variable tolerance?

Comment: @Matt no, sprintf is like printf, but instead of writing to stdout, it writes to a buffer.  I am taking the integer value 400 and turning it into a character array composed of the characters four zero zero null. Read more here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/

Comment: I think I understand this - this will allow my default value of tolerance to be passed into the dialog box, and it will come out as buf? How then do I convert the 'char' output of buf to an integer value I can use in the program? As far as I can see this will leave me with two values: buf (a char type) and tolerance (which won't have changed from the default?)

Comment: @Matt sort of. tolerance is still an int. You can use that wherever you want.  however, your dialog function wanted a string... not an int... So the code above creates a string "400". It's separate from tolerance.

Comment: Thanks. How do I turn that string back into an int and overwrite tolerance with that then? Sorry if that's what's already been done, I'm new to this and can't yet work out how to test if it's worked... :S